# XComs Not visible in Xcom Section in composer-1.17.1-airflow-2.1.2

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have created a task in my airflow DAG that returns some value and that value should be visible in xcom section on airflow but its not.
I have set do_xcom_push = True
but still it wont show.
I was using Airflow 2.0.0 before this and the same task used to push returned value to xcom but in Airflow 2.1.2 its not happening.
I dont understand what am I missing.
Here is a snippet of airflow task:

> task = python_operator.PythonOperator(task_id="invoke_cf",python_callable=invoke_cloud_function,do_xcom_push=True)

Comment: Share the code of invoke_cloud_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PythonOperator` pushes the return value from the python callable to Xcom by default. There is no need to specify `do_xcom_push=True` - It's the default value of `BaseOperator` (See [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d5a029e119eb50e78b5144e5405f2b249d5e4435/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L518))

if nothing is pushed to Xcom it means that the function `invoke_cloud_function` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Understood , I was using a python function to call a cloud function in gcp and that CF returned a value and I thought that would suffice.
Thanks for your time @Elad